# Android Studio ERROR : Failed build NDK project finish with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to include some native cpp sources in my android app. I'm using Android Studio 3.0 with the gradle build system. I have three modules: my android app, the android opencv libs, the cpp sources (in the jni folder)

The build process gives me the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
Process 'command 'C:/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with 
non-zero exit value 2
```

It seems like the path is wrong, but i already check the ndk-build.cmd file location. This is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
     compileSdkVersion 26
     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sensen.magicapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
     buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "C:/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
}

//add repositories
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.1'
    //add library
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary331')
}
```

I already try to follow every step from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flBlhnEd530 this tutorial. and follow the setup tutorial for opencv from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nv4MEliij14 this video.

as i know, ndk-build should give me some .so files that I can use in my app. But the build of the natives failed. Please help me to solve this. Thankyou in advance.